# How can I fix the problem of IDA view and corresponding HEX view not being in sync?

Tags: ida

When I place my cursor on an instruction (on the address, opcode or operand) in the IDA-view, and switch immediately to HEX-view, I expected the hex bytes corresponding to the instructions to be selected. However, IDA 7.0.171130 (x86_64) is not behaving as expected.

As an example, I have selected the address `0x8000328` in the IDA view (the cursor is not visible in the screenshot) which is a `mov` instruction. However, the HEX-view shows `E8 D9 04 00 00` highlighted with the cursor on it; which is a `call` instruction.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you validate that your Hex-View is Synchronized with the IDA View?

In order to do this, go to the Hex View tab, Right Click anywhere in the view and choose "**Synchronize With > IDA View**":

[image]

This works fine for me in version 7.0.1709

Comment: Exactly that was the problem. Why on Earth would some not want to be in sync? Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Imagine, for example, reading an assembly code in the IDA View that manipulates an array of bytes in another address. One might want to see the assembly in the IDA View and at the same time to open the Hex View on this structure of bytes.

Comment: Makes sense :-)